# Operating Systems Deadlocks

Tags: timer, operating-system, system, deadlock

Consider the following procedure to eliminate deadlock: When a process requests a resource, it specifies a time limit. If the process blocks because the resource is not available, a timer is started. If the time limit is exceeded, the process is released and allowed to run again. Does this eliminate deadlock? Why or why not?

Answer (score 0):

possibly because deadlock involved in this case not only depends on the resources  acquired by the processes involved but also processes uses a clock/timer  mechanism
to peform a cascading rollback until . Deadlock is removed .

Answer (score 0):

That does not stop deadlocks. It would just stop a process from being blocked when one has occurred.